# Opencv Compilation error with Eclipse Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I am trying to write a simple OpenCV program using Eclipse of reading an image and simply displaying it. I have included all the libraries and paths in the respective folders. But still I am getting this error:

```
  Multiple markers at this line
- Line breakpoint: test.cpp [line: 11]
- within this context
- character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]
```

The image of the error is attached: [Error on Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2StA.png)

Please help me out, thanks in advance !!

Comment: First mistake is you need to read image like this `Mat img = imread("image_path);` and second Why you have included `highgui.h` two times?

Comment: Actually, I got this from a video on youtube hence wrote it like that. Please tell me the correct procedure then !!

Comment: Image you have provided is of error tab.Can you please post image of console output?